# Extracting youtube data with the tuber package

Tags: r, oauth, youtube

I tried to start working the "tuber" package. A tutorial on how to use this package can be found here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-the-tuber-package-to-analyse-a-youtube-channel/

Now I've set up OAuth 2.0 client in my google developer account (web client). However when i try to log in with my details like this:

```
user <- my_user_name
key <-  my_key 

yt_oauth(my_user_name, my_key, token = '')
```

I get the following error:

The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient

Answer (score 0):

When creating your *OAuth client ID*, set `http://localhost:1410/` as *Authorized redirect URIs*. You may need to edit and update your existing client ID.

Comment: Thanks @lukeA for your response. I tried it but the problem persists. Als I get a prompt for an authorization code in R. Any thoughts?